# Read bytes of interlaced PNG in C

Tags: c, binary, png

Ive been trying to make my own PNG reader in C and ive gotten to the point where it works normally but I want to try and expand its support. I noticed that while uncommon, interlaced png's do exist. Now, I want the goal of my reader simply to return an array of rgba values cooresponding to each pixel in top left to bottom right order. I would not be creating or displaying any pngs.

based on what i saw on the wikipedia for [Adam7 Interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam7_algorithm) (the type pngs use) i would most have to add support for it by organizing the final array according to Adam7. However, when I reviewed the [Interlacing and Progressive Display section](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.6) of libpng (one of the sources i was using), it stated:

> Note that, although I've described the method in terms of 8 × 8 tiles, pixels for any given pass are stored as complete rows, not as tiled groups. For example, the fifth pass consists of every other pixel in the entire third row of the image, followed by every other pixel in the seventh row, and so on.

This makes it seem as though the interlacing is meat for the program in which displays it to use, rather than the information itself being stored using the Adam7 Algorithm.

My question now is, If im not displaying the png, does interlacing matter? And if so, could someone provide an example of how to uninterlace the information? Because this aspect still confuses me.